# Is a "clickable" element in Selenium also imply that it is "visible and present"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In the Selenium framework,  does ExpectedConditions.elementIsClickable  imply that the element is also  "visible, enabled, and present".  The ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocatedBy  appears to be just a simple findElement call on its own.

By looking at the source code, here is what I gleamed so far about ExpectedConditions behaviors, from the methods :

```
1.  findElement() = can throw NoSuchElementException, or WebDriverException
2.  elementToBeClickable() = is visible, !null, and enabled, catches
      a StaleElementReferenceException
3.  visbilityOf()  =   displayed, catches no exception
4.  presenceOfElementLocated()  =   simple findElement call,  catches findElement() 
      exceptions
5.  stalenessOf() =  true if findElement succeeds, can catch StaleElementReferenceException,
      or findElement() exceptions
6.  visibilityOfElementLocated() = same as stalenessOf, can catch 
      StaleElementReferenceException or the findElement() exceptions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a clickable element requires element to be visible. `Click()` will fail and throw a  `ElementNotVisibleException` if the element is hidden.

Example: for the below hidden `span`, `Click()` will throw  a `ElementNotVisibleException` with message `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`.

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("data:text/html,<span id=\"hello\" style=\"display:none;\">Hello</span>");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("hello")).Click();
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Thank you! Thank you!  You just gave me a way to write unit tests for my methods without needing a external website!  I thank you so much!  Now I can write unit tests to prove these things for myself.  Very happy.

Comment: :) Although, I don't think _clickable_ implies _enabled_, as it is possible to click a disabled element also - it just won't do anything.

Comment: I actually found a more detailed explanation of how these work in the WebDriver spec.  So, by examining the source code and spec gives me at least a vague idea of what is going on.

Comment: Yes the spec clearly defines the `click` method requiring `The element MUST be displayed`. The implementation of the click method (14.3.1.1) is different for `select` elements, and might require scrolling into view an element.

Answer (score 0):

Clickable means that element is Visible and Enabled. Another words element is Displayed and Enabled.
You can always check [ExpectedConditions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java) implementation in case any doubt.